# set max time to download images with wget

Tags: matlab, timer, wget

I know that the title sounds familiar, but up to know I wasn't able to find anything that worked for what I am doing. This is code I've been trying so far:

```
t = timer('TimerFcn', 'return;', 'StartDelay', 10);
        downloaded=false;
        start(t)
        while(downloaded==false)
                url = (urlsCell{Pool(l)});
                command = [wgetPath, ' --timeout=10 -nv -P '];
                outputFolder = [tmpDir, ' '];
                cmd = [command, outputFolder, url];
                system(cmd);
                downloaded=true;
        end
```

Basically, I cycle over the cell array urlsCell, that contains a list of URLs, picking a random URL and passing it to `wget` to download an image.

In my intentions, this code should wait a maximum of 10 seconds trying to download the image and if takes longer, skip to the next URL.
Still, it often happens that the program stops, waiting far more than 10 seconds.

Comment: Edited your post to reduce it to a single question. Here is what I removed, consider making a new question:
The second problem is that it sometimes gets stuck returning the following line:
*Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.*
and it only moves on if I do ctrl+c, to stop the current wget. 
After having downloaded an image, the program checks if it is a .jpg/.JPG file and if MatLab can read the image with imread. If the two tests go well, the image is moved to a directory; images are downloaded until the directory contains a number n of good images (.jpg/.JPG and matlab readable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wget retries by default:

> --tries=number
>              Set number of retries to number.  Specify 0 or inf for infinite
>              retrying.  The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception
>              of fatal errors like "connection refused" or "not found" (404),
>              which are not retried.

So add in

> --tries=1

for a one-shot attempt